# Taking inner class from new class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, inner-classes

I want to access `class B` (a subclass of `AsyncTask`) from `class C` where `class B` is an inner class of `class A`.

My code structure was

```
 class A{
     class B extends AsyncTask<>(){
     }
 }

 class C{
     public void method() {
       //here I want to access class B.
     }
 }
```

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
 class A{
      Class B extends AsyncTask<>(){
      }
    }



Class C{
   public void method()
   {
      //First create root class object. Then call sub class and execute it as 
      //below
      new ClassA().new ClassB().execute();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make `Class B` as public.

```
class A{
    public class B extends AsyncTask<>(){

    }
}
```

Then call it inside your `Class C` method.

```
class C{
  public void method(){
    A a = new A();
    A.B b = a.new B();
    b.execute();
  }
}
```

As a general note: Avoid an inner class `AsyncTask` because it can cause memory leak since it holds an implicit reference to your `class A`. It means that even if `class A` is destroyed your `AsyncTask` might outlive and will not release your `class A`, so that's a memory leak.

The easiest solution for that is making the `AsyncTask` static.

```
class A{
    public static class B extends AsyncTask<>(){

    }
}

class C{
   public void method(){
      B b = new B();
      b.execute();
   }
}
```

Aside from making the inner `AsyncTask` subclass as static you can also consider `WeakReference` as alternative solution.